# Delphi TTask Android service

Tags: android, delphi

I do not know how can I use correctly the TTask in Delphi.

I created a TTask.

```
syncTask := ttask.Create(SyncMysqlDatabase);
```

The following code is in the onlocationchangeevent (location sensor).
Every time when onlocationchangeevent triggered run this code:

```
if (syncTask.Status <> ttaskstatus.Running) then
  begin
    logi('syncTask.Start');
    syncTask.Start;
  end;
```

But when I try to start again (after completed) the task again I get the following exception:

> Cannot start a task that has already completed

Could anyone help me, please? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory:

> Cannot start a task **that has already completed**.

A `TTask` can only be started one time.  Once completed, you must free it and create a new `TTask`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a ITask Variable and assign your TTask to it.

You can then wait for the Task to complete before instantiating it again

like so:

```
private
  aTask: TTask;

...

Procedure LocationChanged;
begin
  if Assigned(aTask) then
  begin  
    while not TTask.WaitForAll([aTask], 10000) do
      break;
  end;

  aTask := TTask.Run(procedure()
                     begin
                       // Do Your Stuff
                     end);
end;
```

*I'm not sure if my Assigned(aTask) code would work but basically just check if aTask has a task assigned to it*

since it looks like you're doing an android service I'm guessing you're not too hung up on "hanging" the main thread - this code snippet would do that